# After submitting contact form for page just refreshes

Tags: php, html, forms

When I submit this contact form all that happens is that the page refreshes. No mail is sent and no error message. I am sending it from local host but I already know it works because I sent an email with the same contact form but when I add validation it no longer works. I'm just very confused on why it refreshes.

HTML

```
<section id="contact">
            <h1 class="section-header">Contact Us Directly</h1>
            <h4 class="text-center">Have any quesitons not answered in the <span><a href="questions.php">Questions Page</a></span>.</h4>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" value="<?php $firstname ?>" placeholder="Your name.." tabindex="1" autofocus> <span class="error"><?php $firstname_error ?></span>
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" value="<?php $lastname ?>" placeholder="Your last name.." tabindex="2"> <span class="error"><?php $lastname_error ?></span>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php $email ?>" placeholder="Your email.." tabindex="3"> <span class="error"><?php $email_error ?></span>
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea id="subject" name="message" value="<?php $message ?>" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px" tabindex="4"> </textarea> <span class="error"><?php $message_error ?></span>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="5"> <span class="success"><?php $success ?></span> </form>
        </section>
```

PHP

```
 <?php

  $firstname_error = $lastname_error = $email_error = $message_error = "";
  $firstname = $lastname = $email = $message = $success = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
    $firstname_error = "First name is required";
  } else {
    $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $firstname)) {
        $firstname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["lastname"])) {
    $lastname_error = "Last name is required";
} else {
    $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname)) {
        $lastname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
} else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $email_error = "Invalid email format";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message_error = "Message is required";
} else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
}


if ($firstname_error == '' and $lastname_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $message_error == '' ){
    $Body = "";
    $Body .= "Firstname: ";
    $Body .= $firstname;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Lastname: ";
    $Body .= $lastname;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Email: ";
    $Body .= $email;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Message: ";
    $Body .= $message;
    $Body .= "\n";

    $EmailFrom = localhost;
    $EmailTo = "testrepairmail69@gmail.com";
    $Subject = "New Order From tabletscreenfixer.com";
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$email>");
    if ($success){
        print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
        $firstname = $lastname = $email = $message = '';
    }else{
        print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactfail.php\">";
        $firstname = $lastname = $email = $message = '';
    } 
 }
 }
    function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: well for one thing, your `value="<?php $x_variables ?>"` don't do much without being echo'd and are probably going to throw you undefined variable notices; "if" you've error reporting set to catch and display, something you should be doing during testing.

Comment: and if this `$EmailFrom = localhost;` is your actual code; error reporting should be throwing you an undefined constant notice about it, since it's not quoted.

Comment: But that worked before I put in the validation I thought it was the proper way to do it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php set to catch and display, look at your HTML source and use `var_dump();` on $_POST and variables.

Comment: Oh it says that the variables aren't declared but they should be

Comment: Oh it says that the variables aren't declared that's because you're declaring them in the php file but using them in html file

Comment: No the index page is a php file as well anyway I've scrapped that code and started fresh it been going well so far